# Flutter Project crashes when I create it and shows the cmd and disappears quickly

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

When I start a new flutter project or run any flutter commands in git bash or in the cmd it shows another cmd window and writes a lot of things  in it quickly then disappears and the window that I wrote the flutter command in it doesn't accept any other commands

OS: Windows 7

#### what happened with more details:

1-I installed PowerShell version 5.1 as seen in installation documentation in Flutter Docs.

[image of powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSTlf.png)

2- I installed JDK and sit its PATH User variable to

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin

3- I installed flutter SDK and sit its PATH User variable to

C:\src\flutter\bin

4-I downloaded android studio and SDKs and sat ANDROID_HOME user variable manually to

C:\Users\Bassam\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

[image of the downloaded SDKs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDYlZ.png)

#### 5-After these steps the problem showed up

I took a photo of what cmd says

[flutter doctor result (best image I could take)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAfSe.png)

- system variable Path:

%SystemRoot%\system32;

%SystemRoot%;

%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;

%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;

%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;

%ANDROID_HOME%\tools\bin;

%ANDROID_HOME%\platformtools;

C:\src\flutter\bin;

%systemroot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;

C:\Program Files\Git\cmd`

- User variable Path:

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin;

C:\src\flutter\bin;

C:\Users\Bassam\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;

Comment: flutter doctor is not clear. I think you are not executing the flutter doctor. Try typing "flutter doctor" in cmd and check if there are any others. I should possibly solve your problem.

Comment: I edited it @BalaGanesh and I made sure it is "flutter doctor" it is the same result.

Comment: post the flutter doctor output. The output of flutter doctor won't look like as you previously posted.

Comment: @BalaGanesh that's exactly the issue when I run any command it gives the same output every time and as I mentioned when I write command it shows a new cmd window and prints the result in it and then disappears like flash. I made sure that I wrote "flutter doctor" and the result is the same

Comment: Reinstall the flutter package, delete the flutter path in path sys variable(you have multiple flutter paths). Then try again

Comment: It Worked! Thanks a lot!